# NoSQL databases for large lists, cannot fit in memory

Tags: database, nosql, bigdata

In an effort to speed up reporting, I'm looking for a way of quickly storing data into an easy key/value store.  There are millions of unique keys, and each key can have millions of children, such as:

```
key1: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ...]
key2: [a, x, y, z]
```

Both the keys and the individual values are strings; the values should be a collection of unique strings (i.e., a set).  There is an emphasis on heavy writes, and less frequent reads.  The issue is, the data set is hundreds of gigabytes in size.  I was originally interested in Redis, but the fact that the Virtual Memory (the ability to store the values on disk) is being deprecated means it's not going to be useful for this.

What kind of data stores should I be looking at?  Many KV stores have limits on the size of their values, others are less memory efficient and would cause the memory sizes to balloon.  The inability to manipulate the values in place is also limiting, because then it requires reading a significant amount of data, and then writing it again.

My question is: is there a specific subset of data stores that I should be looking at?  Is what I'm attempting to do feasible?  Or is there simply no way to efficiently do this in real-time?

Comment: have you read REDIS FAQ http://redis.io/topics/faq ?  You might get some clearity on whether REDIS is solution your application.

Comment: Yes, and as mentioned, the data set is far too large to fit into memory, and the amount of clustering required to do so is not feasible (either from a technical or financial stand point).  Since Redis has deprecated the Virtual Memory, that means the entire data set--keys and values both--must fit in memory, per cluster.